# Finding lines that are not connected to network in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, network, gap

How can I find lines that are not connected to a network and identify "gaps" in a network?

See example below:

[image]

Comment: what makes you thin the top red circle would be connected?

Comment: @BERA: That is exactly what I am looking for. But I don't understand why the tolerance has to be in degrees no matter if I have a layer projected in UTM or WGS84....